# My code (a python guessing-game) continues to return "you guessed to high," even when I input 9, the highest value in the range

Tags: python

I think the problem is the loop is not ending even when the right number is input. However, the line `(while choice != a :)` should prevent that, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 9)
choice = int(input("give me a number"))

while choice != a :
    if choice > a:
        choice = int(input("You guessed too high. Please guess again"))
    elif choice < a:
        choice = int(input("You guessed to low. Please guess again"))

print("You won")
```

Comment: Can you explain what your issue is? The code as given seems to work correctly.

Comment: `a` is randomly produced so it could be any value in the specified range that is why when you select 9 it could be too high.

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting the same value when I was guessing so I immediately assumed it was wrong. I guess I underestimated my code haha

Comment: Your while loop will never end and won't ask user for a new input if in first attempt `choice != a`. So, you should ask for new input at the end of the while loop, after elif condition.

Comment: @Jeet that's not true at all, it correctly asks for input and ends the loop if the first choice didn't equal `a`. Or if it did. There are no such logic errors here. Why did you think that?

Comment: @RandomDavis My bad. I missed that input statement inside while loop.

Comment: Sooo, is there still a problem here?